# How to scroll textarea in iOS using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I am making an application for iOS and Android using PhoneGap.

On one screen, I need to hide the keyboard when the user clicks outside the textarea. Also, the textarea should be scrollable when we enter text or fill text dynamically.

For testing, I am using iPhone 3GS and simulator.
Is still no any way to do this?